# I have bug with ContextMenu on rounded views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, contextmenu

I'm experiencing an issue with the display of my View when I invoke the context menu. The View appears correctly without the context menu, but there seems to be a problem when it's present. If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it.

[Contex View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ2rU.png)
[Travel View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKleq.png)]

```
TravelView(travel: travel)
       .contextMenu {
                     VStack {
                     Button(action: {}) {
                     Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                                            }
                      }
```

TravelView looks like

```
VStack{

     // some code 
      }  
    .background(Color.green.opacity(0.8))
    .cornerRadius(20)
    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.5), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 2)
```

I need to remove the frames on the capsule and the shadows on the font

Answer (score 2):

Add
`.contentShape(.contextMenuPreview, RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))` just before the `.contextMenu` modifier like this:

```swift
TravelView(travel: travel)
    .contentShape(.contextMenuPreview, RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)) // this 20 is the corner radius used in your `TravelView`
    .contextMenu {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
            }
        }
```

Hope it solves the issue.